# Regular singular point of non-linear ODE

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider a system of ordinary differential equations of the form
$$
\dot{x}(t) + \frac{1}{t}Ax(t) = B(x(t))
$$
where $x(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is a constant matrix, and $B: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is homogeneous of degree $2$, i.e. $B(\lambda x) = \lambda^2 B(x)$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

What is known about existence of solutions near $t = 0$?

If it were not for the quadratic term, the point $t = 0$ would be a **regular singular point** of the ODE and then we could use the Frobenius method. But in all the books I have, regular singular points are only discussed for *linear* systems.

Comment: X-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/366288